# How to check if svg circle is having specified class?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Following is my code. I have created a circle with class "cir". How to check whether my circle is having that class or not?

```
 circle = lineGroup.selectAll("circle")
                        .data(circlePoints);
                    // kill old circles
                    circle.exit()
                        .transition()
                        .attr("r", 0)
                        .remove();
                    // new circles

                    circle.enter().append("circle");
                    circle.attr("cx", function(d, i) {
                            return d.x;
                        })
                        .attr("cy", function(d, i) {
                            return d.y;
                        })
                        .attr('r','8')
                        .attr("class","cir")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In D3, `attr` is both a setter and a getter. So, in a selection, if you write:

```
selection.attr("class", "foo")
```

You are assigning a class `foo` to that selection. But if you write only

```
selection.attr("class")
```

You get the class of that selection.

Check the code below, it logs in the console the class of your circles:

```js
var data = [50, 100, 150];

var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", 200)
 .attr("height", 200);
 
var circles = svg.selectAll(".circles")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("circle");

circles.attr("cx", function(d) {return d;})
    .attr("cy", function(d) {return d;})
  .attr('r','8')
    .attr("class","cir"); 
  
var myClass = circles.attr("class");

console.log(myClass);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

So, to get the class of your circle, you can use:

```
var myClass = circles.attr("class");
console.log(myClass);
```

Or:

```
var myClass = svg.selectAll("circle").attr("class");
console.log(myClass);
```

Comment: if(lineGroup.selectAll("circle")
                  .data(circlePoints)
                  .enter()
                  .append("circle")
                  .attr("class","cir")) { //to do }

Comment: No, just `if(circle.attr("class") == "foo"){ //do things }`